# Is the 'pathutil' ruby gem compatible with jekyll (v3.9.0) and ruby (v3.0.0)?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, jekyll

**My problem:** I have a jekyll-based static website; after running `bundle exec jekyll serve` (as directed by the jekyll docs) I get the stack trace below. The markdown file I've created for that blog post file in the stack trace is entirely standard syntax. I've googled the specific error and get posts for similar errors that don't solve my problem. I've also scoured the jekyll docs to see if there are any incompatibilities with no luck.

```
           Writing: /home/REDACTED/projects/thomdlee.github.io/_site/jekyll/update/2020/12/28/currently-in-maintenance.html
                    done in 0.356 seconds.
jekyll 3.9.0 | Error:  no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer
/home/REDACTED/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pathutil-0.16.2/lib/pathutil.rb:502:in `read': no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer (TypeError)
        from /home/REDACTED/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pathutil-0.16.2/lib/pathutil.rb:502:in `read'
```

All my code can be found here on github: https://github.com/thomdlee/thomdlee.github.io

**My environment:**

- Ubuntu 20.10 (running in WSL 2 on Windows 10)
- Ruby v3.0.0
- Jekyll (gem) v3.9.0
- pathutil (gem) v0.16.2

Comment: I hit the same problem you did, same platform and WSL2. I’m nervous to say I have an answer as I just entirely purged my ruby configuration. However, using rbenv, I’m using Ruby 2.7.2, and Jekyll 4.2.0 by updating the Gemfile. Performance is MUCH better now, too. Try downgrading Ruby and upgrading Jekyll?

Comment: so for now basically the answer is no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `pathutil` have an issue with deprecation [Link](https://github.com/envygeeks/pathutil/pull/5)

I had a same issue, but downgrading Ruby to 2.7.x solve this.

Comment: for arch user see [rvm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/RVM#Installing_RVM).

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72359578/399105):

> Ruby 3.0 deprecated using the last argument as keyword parameters. A double splat ** has to be added before the variable for the behavior to be supported.

Here's how I applied the patch to pathutil:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/, kwd/, **kwd/' $(gem which pathutil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only solution still is to downgrade.

On Arch Linux you can do

```
sudo pacman -S ruby2.7
cd /PATH/TO/YOUR/JEKYLL/PROJECT
bundle-2.7 install
bundle-2.7 exec jekyll serve
```

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=265534

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but in MacOS environment.

To fix it I've ran the following command on the project folder:

`bundler update`