# jekyll serve throws 'no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer ' error

Tags: jekyll

I am following Michael Hartl's Learn Enough CSS course. My current folder layout is as follow:

```
- _layouts
- _site
index.html
```

where `index.html` is:

```
---
layout: test
---
```

and I have `test.html` in `_layouts` as:

```
Hello again, world.
```

Whenever I run `jekyll serve`, I get this error:

```
Error reading file /Users/pj/Documents/LETGD/repos/pohjie.github.io/_layouts/test.html: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer 
Error reading file /Users/pj/Documents/LETGD/repos/pohjie.github.io/index.html: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer
```

Does anyone have any idea what's happening? I'm using M1 MacBook, not sure if that is a possible cause as I spent a lot of time install Ruby as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see this code in your [github repo](https://github.com/pohjie/pohjie.github.io), if you could commit it, it would help. In the meanwhile, can you add to your question the output of `bundle exec jekyll build --trace`.

Comment: @BradWest Thanks for replying! It turns out I did not do `gem install bundler`, which is why I had issues with jekyll!

Comment: are u using a newer version of ruby? x=> 3?

Answer (score 6):

While downgrading certainly works, it may be pretty annoying and (depending on where you need this) problematic. If you just want a simple workaround, you can make use of the fact that `jekyll build` still works with Ruby 3 and just serve the page separately:

```
bundler exec jekyll build && bash -c 'cd _site && python -m http.server 3000'
```

The only downside of this is that you lose the automatic reload. If you change anything, you need to restart jekyll. But you can run this in a Ruby 3 environment without fiddling with the environment itself.

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading to Ruby 2.7 is an option ([as others have said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580565/399105)) which I didn't feel like doing, so I did this instead:

1. Apply the patch to pathutil

   From [Liviu Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72359578/399105):

   > Ruby 3.0 deprecated using the last argument as keyword parameters. A double splat ** has to be added before the variable for the behavior to be supported.

   Here's how I applied the patch locally:

   ```
   sudo sed -i.bak 's/, kwd/, **kwd/' $(gem which pathutil)
   ```
2. After that I got another error:

   ```
   /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
   ```

   Which I fixed by running (from [bundle exec jekyll serve: cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492996/399105)):

   ```
   bundle add webrick
   ```

Comment: This is what I was expecting to read. What is the real problem and some compatible solution. Therefore, I got app running. I noted that code frequency in Jekyll's repo in Github is almost inexistent, what says much about this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from this [source](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/error-no-implicit-conversion-of-hash-into-integer/5890/2):-

> Github-Pages uses Jekyll 3.9, which isn’t compatible with Ruby 3.
> Downgrading to Ruby 2.7 should avoid the problem.

This worked for me.

Comment: [Similarly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66609729/2368696), short fix just downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 3.0 deprecated **using the last argument as keyword parameters**. A double splat ** has to be added before the variable for the behavior to be supported.

It's fairly straightforward to amend locally; the relevant patch is found: [here](https://github.com/envygeeks/pathutil/pull/5/commits/3451a10c362fc867b20c7e471a551b31c40a0246/)

Which needs to be applid to:

> /home/<your_user_name>/gems/gems/pathutil-0.16.2/lib/pathutil.rb

Answer (score 0):

To stay with Ruby 3 or later, you can specify this [Ruby 3 compatible update](https://github.com/sdogruyol/pathutil) in your Gemfile:

```
gem "pathutil", github: "sdogruyol/pathutil", ref: '6ab144a7706c2bc5fa0dfdfa498e94ff66e944c6'
```

A full Gemfile would then look something like below. (I've also included webrick here as it's [a separate workaround needed for Ruby 3](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523#issuecomment-751409319) and later).

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
gem "jekyll"
gem "webrick"
gem "pathutil", github: "sdogruyol/pathutil", ref: '6ab144a7706c2bc5fa0dfdfa498e94ff66e944c6'

# if you want jekyll plugins
# group :jekyll_plugins do
  # gem 'jekyll-paginate'
  # (etc)
# end
```

Then run `bundle update` and `bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental` as usual.